# merge 2 objects in sculpt mode

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

So I've been studying the anatomy for a couple of days and I made de legs separately from the upper body. I now want to merge those 2 but I don't know exactly how I've tried a Boolean tool but it's not really working. Can you guys help me pls.

Thanks in advance !
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you join them manually in the lower multiresolution? I woudl suggest the sculpt tools addon, but that is mainly for the dynamic topology sculpting with destructive sculpting.

Comment: Why is boolean not working?

Comment: The real solution would be to use boolean operation to do that. We can try to help you to solve this problem if you tell us why it is'nt "really" working

Comment: Well my advise is to go Zbrush. There you can join the meshes and re-project the sculpted detail so you will still have all the sculpted subdivisions. By doing join operation or boolean in Blender you will loose the multires data, the operation is destructive. You will end up with one-piece high-poly but no corresponding low-poly.

Answer (score -1):

To merge the legs with the torso, select the two objects (the legs and the torso) in either order, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>J key</kbd>. The object you select first gets merged into the object you select last, so if the first object you select is the legs, and the second is the torso, the surviving object is the torso. If the first object you select is the torso, then the surviving object is the leg object.

But why do you *want* to merge the legs with the body? In blender, for one element of a character (like a leg or an arm) to articulate relative to another element (like a torso) the elements need to be separate objects. After merging (or "joining") the legs to the body, moving the legs relative to the body (or the body relative to the legs) becomes impossible with ordinary modeling and animation techniques. So, if you're modeling a non-movable statue, go ahead and join the objects. If the character is to be animated, leave them separate. In fact, if the character is to be animated, you probably want to separate the legs into four objects, one object for each of the lower legs and and one for each of the upper. Similarly, when you get there, if the feet and hand are to be able to articulate, each foot and hand will need to consist of multiple objects, depending upon how detailed you want the animation to be.

To preserve the ability to animate the character, you would use a different mechanism in Blender: you'd parent one object, for example an upper leg, to another object, the torso, and in turn, parent the lower leg to the upper. There are several tutorials available on Youtube easily located by using your favorite search engine with the parameters "Blender tutorial parent objects".

Comment: Hi thx for the answer. I actually wanted to merge the 2 objects to make them look like one because now you can clearly see where the legs stop and where the torso begins.And i'm not planning on animating it.

Comment: Joining the two objects will not make them "look like one", it will **make** them one.

Comment: This answers the question if the first paragraph, although I would add that you may want to connect the mesh pieces in edit mode after joining the objects. However the rest of this answer ranges from misleading to incorrect with regards to character animation. Characters are normally a single mesh weighted to an armature, which is then used to animate them.

Comment: Go ahead and edit my answer to improve it, @Sazerac. My Blender experience thus far has mainly involved static objects and I am only now beginning to consider animations, but mainly with inanimate objects, not characters. The answer contained a reasonably accurate statement of my understanding at the time I wrote it, but I make no claims to any particular level of expertise in animation.

Comment: @brasshat I have added a mention of the aramature modifier and a description of retopology that will be helpful if animation is a target.